# Need to implement destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I am working on c++11 project. In it I have a `shared_ptr` holding `std::string` data.

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base() : Base(string()) {}
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  Base(const string &str) {
    str_ = std::make_shared<string>(str);
  }
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> str_;
};
```

My question is: here should I implement destructor to free `str_`, copy constructor and assignment operator to take care of copies?
Is it enough if I rely on default ones provided by the compiler?
I want to allow creating objects of this class either in the stack by `Base b1("string");` or in the heap by `Base *b1 = new Base("string");`

Comment: No, you don't need to create them.

Comment: Why are you using a shared_ptr to hold the string? Do you really want copies of this object to refer to the very same string? If so, why?

Comment: You can rely on default implementations provided by compiler because simple memberwise-copy supplied by defaults is enough.

Comment: Normally in a class with a virtual dtor you want to **delete** copy and move constructors and assignment operators or at least make them private/protected.

Comment: @RichardHodges yes I want that when i have two objects of type base if I do b1 = b2 modifying str_ on b2 modifies also str_ in b1. Is there better way to do it ?

Comment: in that case I would make the string a static member. Imho that makes the intent more clear. No need to bother with pointers

Comment: @flyx why cannot I do that? I have tested and it works.

Comment: @RuLoViC ok, if that's the behaviour you want. Be careful of simultaneous access across threads. As it stands, this class will not be thread-safe while accessing the shared string. If that doesn't matter in your project, at least make it clear in the documentation that `Base` is not safe for concurrent access.

Comment: @RichardHodges, ok thanks, if I do it using static method would it be thread-safe? or not at all?

Comment: @RuLoViC no. If you want it to be thread-safe, you'll need to hold a shared pointer to a structure that contains both the string and a mutex. you'll also need to keep the mutex locked while you access the string. To comment any further I'd need to know the use case. You might benefit from pub;ishing your design on codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b
 with an explanation of the use case.

Comment: @M.M you're right. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor and assignment operators (both copy and move) will be "correct".  The reason I put "correct" in quotations is that I have concerns that you intend to derive classes from this `Base` class (given the virtual destructor, and the name), and if you write something like:

```
Base *p1 = new Derived1("foo", "bar");
Base *p2 = new Derived1("bar", "foo");
*p1 = *p2;   // Will compile, but probably won't do what you want.
```

Specifically, the assignment will copy the `Base` part of the object pointed to by `p2`, but will not copy any `Derived1` parts.

I would either delete the constructor and assignment operators or make them protected.

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base() : Base(string()) {}
//Either
  Base(const Base& rhs) = delete;
  Base& operator=(const Base& rhs) = delete;
//OR
protected:
  Base(const Base&rhs) = default;
  Base& operator=(const Base& rhs) = default;
  Base(Base&&rhs) = default;
  Base& operator=(Base&& rhs) = default;
public:
//END
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  Base(const string &str) {
    str_ = std::make_shared<string>(str);
  }
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> str_;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I will create derived classes from it
Please cpuld you elaborate, why should I either "protect" them or disable them?
Thanks

Comment: Because if you don't, then `*p1 = *p2` will assign the base class values *but  not the derived elements!*.  I have edited the answer